# Differentiate a function contains modules of a complex vector

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

The function $f$ has form: $$f(x)=\log (1+ |z^\intercal x|^2)$$
where $z\in C^n, x\in C^n$ are two complex vectors.

How to differentiate $f$ with respect to $x$: $$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=?$$

Any comment would be highly appreciated

Comment: Use the chain rule

Comment: @NinadMunshi Sorry I don't have much experience dealing with complex numbers. Is there any difference from handling the real variables? Shall I just consider the absolute part as  (Re(z'x)^2 + Im(z'x)^2) and do the differentiation w.r.t x? Thanks.

Comment: This is not a complex numbers issue, this is a matrix calculus issue